# Save fingerprints on Samsung galaxy phones?

Tags: android, fingerprint, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-knox

So, I'm trying to build an application on the Samsung Galaxy S6 using the fingerprint scanner.  I have Samsung's Pass SDK and see that it's pretty simple to authenticate a user while using the phone.  However, I need to authenticate a user's fingerprints on a server.  I'm not sure how to go about this.  Are the fingerprints stored somewhere on the phone that I need root privileges to get to?

I'm beginning to think this is a lost cause, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share some code implementation so far? Here are some official guide: http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000145L and all the official documentation: http://developer.samsung.com/resources/pass

Comment: I have no familiarity with samsung's implementation, but I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. You do not have access to the fingerprints for security reasons.

Comment: I don't have any code yet because I'm trying to figure out if it's possible, first.  I can see how to authenticate a user to use an application on the phone, but I just need to know where the data is stored because I want to authenticate a user with a server (similar to Samsung Knox).  If the data isn't available, can I use the hardware on the phone to take my fingerprint and save it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung or iPhone only provide SDK to verify 1 user (user of device) but others manufacturers provide a SDK to get fingerprint image or template.

There's some fingerprint scanners compatible with Android Platform and with SDK for Android. Scanners are plugged on USB port so you can't charge tablet and use fingerprint scanner simultaneous. For instance:

- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/fingerprintscanner/
- http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs80h.html
- http://www.crossmatch.com/authentication-hardware/

There's also some devices with integrated fingerprint scanner and with SDK to get fingerprint image or template.